# meteor import global variable how?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Hello i am using Meteor 1.3.5

I have a package in:

```
projectdir/packages/mypackage
```

In this package i defined a global variable:

```
myGlobalVariable = "somedata";
```

Now i have a myapi.js in:

```
projectdir/imports/api/myservice
```

I want to use myGlobalVariable in myapi.js. So i included this line:

```
import {myGlobalVariable} from 'meteor/mypackage';
```

In my code the global variable is still undefined when i enter the code in myapi.js.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can kept the global variable inside the lib/constant.js from here you will be able to access it any where

Any files placed in a folder lib/ anywhere in your app structure will be loaded before every other file

lib/constant.js

`myGlobalVariable = "somedata`"

Comment: does it matter if it is no constant and i want to assign/change values later on?

Answer (score 0):

It is a better practice to have declared variables in your modules and export/import them:

File: `projectdir/packages/mypackage`:

```
export let myGlobalVariable = "somedata";

// You can also export multiple variables in one sentence:
export let name1, name2, …, nameN; // Also can use var
```

If your prefer to have `myGlobalVariable` as global you can do:

```
myGlobalVariable = "somedata";

export myGlobalVariable;
```

File: `projectdir/imports/api/myservice`:

```
import {myGlobalVariable} from 'meteor/mypackage';

// You can also import multiple variables in one sentence:
import {name1, name2, …, nameN} from 'meteor/mypackage';
```

Comment: The "export let" keywords have to be in a special place? I tried to put them inside of my js but i am getting a `SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word`

Comment: You can also use `export var myGlobalVariable;`

Comment: Has it to be in `lib.js`?

Comment: It can be from your package: `projectdir/packages/mypackage`

Comment: I am still getting syntax error on the export keyword